# python switch/case with conditions

Tags: python, function, dictionary, switch-statement

if-else statements are cumbersome. I want to construct a switch/case statement in Python. But switch/case statements in Python are geared towards specific cases such as:

```
def switch(case):
    return {
        "a":fa,
        "b":fb,
    }.get(case, f_default)
```

But I want the case to meet certain conditions as in the following:

```
def descriptor(magnitude):
    return {
        magnitude == 10.0: 'Meteoric',
        magnitude >= 9.0: 'Great',
        magnitude >= 8.0: 'Major',
        magnitude >= 7.0: 'Strong',
        magnitude >= 6.0: 'Moderate',
        magnitude >= 5.0: 'Light',
        magnitude >= 4.0: 'Minor',
        magnitude >= 3.0: 'Very Minor',
        magnitude <= 2.0: 'Micro'
}.get(magnitude, magnitude == True)()
```

My thinking is that the return key in the dictionary is anything that is true. which is why I wrote `magnitude == True`. Can someone give me some guidance, my thoughts are in `magnitude == True` but without it, there is a KeyValue error as expected.

Comment: You should start by printing the dictionary you've built to check what's in it: there'll be at most two values in there.

Comment: "But switch/case statements in Python are geared towards specific cases " *Python does not have switch/case statements*. They aren't geared towards *any* cases. Just use the if-elif-else statements

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to search a sorted list for where between the elements a new value would be inserted. Luckly python already includes the `bisect` module to do it using the very efficient bisection algorithm, which splits the list in two successively until the correct value is found:

```
import bisect
l = sorted([
    (10.0, 'Meteoric'),
    (9.0, 'Great'),
    (8.0, 'Major'),
    (7.0, 'Strong'),
    (6.0, 'Moderate'),
    (5.0, 'Light'),
    (4.0, 'Minor'),
    (3.0, 'Very Minor'),
    (2.0, 'Micro'),
])

def descriptor(magnitude):
    return l[bisect.bisect_left(l, (magnitude,))]
```

Usage:

```
>>> descriptor(4.4)
(5.0, 'Light')
>>> descriptor(7.2)
(8.0, 'Major')
>>> descriptor(3.0)
(3.0, 'Very Minor')
```

Comment: You might want to tweak this so that if `descriptor` gets an input larger than 10, it doesn't raise an `IndexError`.